# Perform segue from another class error can't find segue

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, segue

I am trying to perform a segue that will be call form another class than ui view. The final target is that the main view will wait that an URL request is done to go to the next view.

Here my ui view:

```
class LoadingViewController: UIViewController {

     @IBOutlet weak var activityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView!

     override func viewDidLoad() {
          super.viewDidLoad()
     }

     override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
          super.viewDidAppear(animated)

          CardList.retrieveAllCards()
     }

     override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
          super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
     }

     func goToNextView() {
          performSegue(withIdentifier: "segueToMainController", sender:      LoadingViewController.self)        
     }

    class ShowNext {
         class func view(fromViewController: LoadingViewController) {
               fromViewController.goToNextView()
         }
    }
}
```

and here how I call my segue from the other class

```
 let task = session.dataTask(with: request){
        data,response,error in
        do
        {
            if let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as? NSDictionary {
                jsonResultEnd = jsonResult
                //print("SUCCESS:\(jsonResult)")

                LoadingViewController.ShowNext.view(fromViewController: LoadingViewController())
                print("loading ended")
            }
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("ERROR request manager: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
```

Here is the error

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Receiver () has no segue with identifier 'segueToMainController''

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't make any sense to instantiate a new `LoadingViewController` and try to pass that into your class func.  What you need to do is get a reference to your existing `LoadingViewController` and call `goToNextView()` on that.

There are many ways to do this, but one way would be to pass a reference to your `LoadingViewController` as a variable on your other view, and when your async call finishes you can call `self.loadingViewController.goToNextView()`.

You could also use `NotificationCenter` to broadcast from your view that this async call is complete, and observe that notification on your `LoadingViewController` and use that event to trigger the segue:

In your `LoadingViewController`'s `viewDidLoad` method:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(goToNextView), name: Notification.Name("loadingComplete"), object: nil)
```

And in your other view's async callback:

```
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("loadingComplete"), object:
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

So, if I would like to do that by reference, I need to add to my **LoadingViewController** a method like that: 
    class func getLoadingVC() -> LoadingViewController
    {
        return self
    }

and call **getLoadingVC()** in my async call to declare the variable
     let loadingVC = LoadingViewController.getloadingVC()
and call it
     loadingVC.goToNextView()

Comment: I try your solution with the **notification center** but I have another error : *** Assertion failure in void _UIPerformResizeOfTextViewForTextContainer(NSLayoutManager *, UIView<NSTextContainerView> *, NSTextContainer *, NSUInteger)(), /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIFoundation/UIFoundation-543/UIFoundation/TextSystem/NSLayoutManager_Private.m:1619
2018-01-09 00:17:22.970438+0100 CardList[5684:4567419] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Only run on the main thread!'

Comment: No, you wouldn't want to have that `getLoadingVC()` like that.  That makes no sense either.  Instead, when you create your view, set a variable on that view so it has a reference on it.

Comment: And your error is from something else.  You are trying to do something with a UITextView on a background thread.

Comment: yes you right about the **notification center**. I will use this solution. I don't understand the other one.

Comment: The other one is probably better, but go with whatever you prefer.  You'd have to show a lot more of your code for me to be able to help with the other one.

Comment: For now I will use the notification but if I have some issue about it further (like side effect) I will come back to you.